# jQuery all-in-one edit, drag, resize plugin(s)?

Tags: jquery

I want to allow my site visitors to create a customizable and printable label, approximately 2.5" x 3.5" in size.

They will be given a "canvas" (div) in which they can customize several elements that contain text by editing the text, moving the containing element, etc.

Also, they will have two or more image containers to which they can upload their own images to place on the label. They should be able to move the location of the image and resize it while constraining the aspect ratio.

Maybe I'm asking too much, but does anyone know of a plugin or several plugins to help accomplish this? I've looked around and found a few that kind of do parts of what I'm wanting to do.

It's basically a simplified desktop publishing type web app.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @mcgrailm, I've asked 6 questions, 5 got answers, I marked 2 accepted. The other 3, including this one, there were no answers that offered a helpful solution. I already knew that jquery inherently had these capabilities. I was looking for a plugin. Neither answer offered a plugin solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI will let you drag and resize.

Answer (score 0):

there is allot you want to do there and I don't think your gonna find your solution in one plugin your best bet is gonna be to use [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/) and just take it step by step its gonna take time thats all